# NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk environment error Cannot find module 'node-linux-arm64/package.json'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having issues getting my Node.js project to run on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

It was running fine for months, but after the Christmas break, it is now failing.

Here is the output from the eb-engine.log file:

```
[INFO] Executing instruction: Use NPM to install dependencies
[INFO] use npm to install dependencies
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm config set jobs 1
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm --production install

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/app/staging/node_modules/node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node installArchSpecificPackage
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR! throw err;
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-arm64/package.json'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /var/app/staging/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
npm ERR! at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR! at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
npm ERR! at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/app/staging/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:19:27)
npm ERR! at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
npm ERR! code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR! requireStack: [
npm ERR! '/var/app/staging/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'
npm ERR! ]
npm ERR! }
```

This is using the "Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.6.3" platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this helps someone else if they experience this same issue.

The issue was caused by one of my project dependencies.

Within the source code of this dependency, it was requiring a different version of node within its `package.json`.

Removing the dependency on the module within our app resolved the problem.

Comment: which package was it?